# How to turn a regular class into MVC?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am working on a MVC based off of the code that I will be providing. I am having issues because I am fairly new to the subject. I am able to make the view, but when it comes to making the model it is a little more complicated for me. I need some guidance on how to turn the following code into a MVC so I can practice and learn. I been at this for several hours and I decided to come here for help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

 class SayHi extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
// components
protected JLabel helloLabel = new JLabel("Hello");
protected JTextField userInputTextField = new JTextField(20);
private JButton    sayHiBtn    = new JButton("Say Hi");


/** Constructor */
SayHi() {
   //... Layout the components.      
    JPanel content = new JPanel();

    content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    content.add(new JLabel("Enter your name"));
    content.add(userInputTextField);
    content.add(sayHiBtn);
    content.add(helloLabel);



    // Add a mouse listener to the button
    sayHiBtn.addMouseListener(this);

    //... finalize layout
    this.setContentPane(content);
    this.pack();
    this.setTitle("Simple App - Not MVC");

    // The window closing event should probably be passed to the 
    // Controller in a real program, but this is a short example.

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }

// Methods I am forced to implement because of the MouseListener

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    helloLabel.setText("Hello " + userInputTextField.getText());
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    SayHi s = new SayHi();
    s.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Comment: You don't turn a single "regular" class into MVC. You'd need at least 3 classes (model, view, and controller). Still, creating a model absent a framework could be simply creating an `ArrayList<T>` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View only controls the visuals, The Model only controls the data access and the Controller is in charge of the logic that glues the two. 
You could split that class into 3 classes in order to make it a MVC.

All the Jpanel would be located in a View, in the Model you would have all your values, like setting a string to hello and such, while the controller  needs to interact with both the Model and View.

```
private SayHiModel model;
private SayHiView  view;
SayHiController(SayHiModel model, SayHiView  view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view  = view;
    this.model.setValue(model.INITIAL_VALUE);
    view.totalTextField.setText(model.getValue());
    //... Add listeners to the view.
    view.addMultiplyListener(new MultiplyListener());
    view.addClearListener(new ClearListener());
}
```

Just a little hint to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much of a model to work with.

Here's your example code, with one view class, one model class, and one controller class.  The SayHi class is the view class.  The SayHiModel class is the model class.  The SayHiListener class is the controller class.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SayHi implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JLabel helloLabel;

    private JTextField userInputTextField;

    private SayHiModel model;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SayHi());
    }

    public SayHi() {
        this.model = new SayHiModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ... Layout the components.
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        content.add(new JLabel("Enter your name: "));

        userInputTextField = new JTextField(20);
        content.add(userInputTextField);

        JButton sayHiBtn = new JButton("Say Hi");
        // Add a mouse listener to the button
        sayHiBtn.addMouseListener(new SayHiListener(this, model));
        content.add(sayHiBtn);

        helloLabel = new JLabel("Hello");
        content.add(helloLabel);

        // ... finalize layout
        frame = new JFrame("MVC App");

        // The window closing event should probably be passed to the
        // Controller in a real program, but this is a short example.

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public void setHelloLabel(String name) {
        helloLabel.setText("Hello " + name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return userInputTextField.getText().trim();
    }

    public class SayHiModel {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    public class SayHiListener extends MouseAdapter {
        private SayHi sayHi;

        private SayHiModel sayHiModel;

        public SayHiListener(SayHi sayHi, SayHiModel sayHiModel) {
            this.sayHi = sayHi;
            this.sayHiModel = sayHiModel;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            sayHiModel.setName(sayHi.getName());
            sayHi.setHelloLabel(sayHiModel.getName());

            JFrame frame = sayHi.getFrame();
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

}
```